# Is there a way to auto-align or rotate labels with css?

Tags: css

I have a map with a series of polygons, that are labelled with road names, ie. basically a road map. I haven't found a way to align the labels at an angle that matches the roads, they're all horizontal. Is there a way to auto-rotate the labels with lines and polygons? So far I have:

```
stroke: #000000;
stroke-width: 0.5;
label:[name];
font-family:"arial";
font-size:12;
font-fill:black;
```

Comment: I think you'll have to rotate manually.

Comment: Well you can rotate like this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp